# Showing progressbar in listview while downloading

Tags: android, listview, download

There's a "download" button in each listview item. While the button is clicked, it will start a worker thread to down files. And at the same time, the button changed to progressbar and showing the progress rate.

So please show me some proper ways.

Comment: AsyncTask is something you need but does not provide you any good help when it comes to displaying progress bar in list item if your list is long enough to provide scrolling and repetitive getView() call. What I did was, save a HashMap mapping position to progressValue, in AsyncTask, I update the progressValue of this HashMap and call a notifyDataSet. The progress bar that I used in list item is merely 2 ImageView in a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AsyncTask since it has special methods for communicating with the main (UI) thread despite being asynchronous.

Here is an example:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
            ProgressDialog() progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progress.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          // Do work
         return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This should be nested in your activity class and executed like this:

```
new DownloadTask().execute();
```

You will likely need to adjust the asynctask to fit your needs but this will get you started.

Comment: Actually, what puzzles me is that when I click one download button in one listview item and the progressbar showing well, but after I pull&refresh, another progressbar in a different listview item is showed too.

Comment: It was because I reuse the view as followings:@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if(convertView==null)
  {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_item, null);
  }
  AppItem appItem = (AppItem)getItem(position);
  constructView(convertView, appItem);
  return convertView;
 }   But if I remove the if(convertView == null).., the sliding will not be quite smooth. How to solve it?